# Computing subset reciprocals, $\frac1{a+b}+\frac1{a+c}+\frac1{b+c}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, algorithms, generating-functions

I'm interested in computing the sum
$$
H_k = \sum_{S\subseteq T, |S|=k} \frac{1}{\sum_{s\in S} s},
$$
where $T$ is some set of integers.
Obviously this can be done in $|T|^k$ time, enumerating all subsets, but that is painfully slow.

There is a similar problem of computing
$$
G_k = \sum_{S\subseteq T, |S|=k} \prod_{s\in S} s,
$$
which can be easily solved by considering the generating function
$$\prod_{s\in T}(z+s) = \sum_k z^k G_k.$$
We simply expand the product using FFT and pick the desired coefficient of $z$ in $\tilde O(n)$ time.

I'm wondering if we can use the similar expression
$$\int \prod_{s\in T}(z+\exp(t s))dt\Big|_{t=0} = \sum_k z^k H_k$$
to quickly compute each $H_k$?

Or maybe there's another fast algorithm based on dynamic programming or elsewise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Letting
$$
f(x,z)=\prod_{t\in T}(1+x^tz),
$$
you can check that
$$
\int_0^1\frac{f(x,z)-1}{x}\,dx= \sum_k H_k z^k.
$$
This is pretty much exactly the trick you did to evaluate $\sum_k H_kz^k$. The advantage of my version is that $f(x,z)$ is just a bivariate polynomial.  You should be able to quickly compute a product of bivariate polynomials using a [two-dimensional FFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform#Multidimensional_FFTs). To be honest, I have never used a 2D-FFT, so I cannot confirm if this works.

Once you have $f(x,z)$, computing $\int_0^1\frac{f(x,z)-1}{x}\,dx$ is easy.

Comment: I suppose this requires the elements of $T$ to be bounded for the computation of $f(x, z)$ not to be exponential, right?

Comment: That is true.  ${}$